# Firebase UI - Auth - Custom Background only for AuthMethodPicker

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Is it possible to use a custom background for the FirebaseUI.AuthMethodPicker **ONLY**?

I know you can use `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_background</item>` in the firebase ui theme, but this changes the background for **all activities** (e.g. register email, etc.), and thats not what I want.

Thank you already!

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I'm also looking for this. Any news?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize them in the theme with your own style (for firebase UI version 0.6.0 and above) where the theme parent are:-
FirebaseUI.AuthMethodPicker.Logo ,
FirebaseUI.AuthMethodPicker etc.

OR refer to nice github link :-

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me change the ui of the screens that follow the sign in screen

```
<style name="FirebaseUI.WrapperStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@mipmap/bg_login_flow</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">
            @dimen/fui_wrapper_padding_horiz
        </item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/fui_wrapper_padding_horiz
       </item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that allowed me to change only the AuthMethodPicker activity background was to override the whole layout resource file. In essence, you need to copy the **fui_auth_method_picker_layout.xml** from the FirebaseAuthUI github repository and set the background in there. The change there will not result in any of the other activities.